# Visual Studio 2015 IIS issue when building project from NAS

Tags: asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2015, iis-express, nas

I've recently updated my `network` to have a **NAS**.
I have mapped the `NAS drive` to my `computer` and copied across my old `VS projects (asp.net mostly)`.
When I try and build a project which is opened from the mapped drive I get `"Unable to launch the IIS Express Web Server."` However if I copy the project folder to my computers hard drive and run it, it works fine.

> What is going wrong, and why?

I have read AND write permission to the NAS drive so if it needed to edit files it should be able to.

Comment: Mapped drives are not supported. Besides, copying files might lead to broken IIS Express configuration file (as the config file contains the physical path at the original location). I suggest you carefully check that. If you could not fix it, post the configuration file as part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about IIS Express,
I'm using IIS on  Windows Server 2016 TP, Working on it too with VS 2015, so to work propetrly, F.E. Upload files (MVC), Working with folders - tasks witch need permision to write and modify file, I changed permisions for IIS_IUSR.
Hope this will help you to fix your problem.
Respectfully Archil.